# calculating with the date format

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need some help with calculating with the start and stop date format to against the current time following by `20151227135000` and `20151227160500`. I want to calculating with both formats to compare with the current time to see how many minutes the current program is remaining.

**Example:** I use the format `20151227160500` to take it away `20151227135000` to get the full time of the program `25500` which it show as 2 hours and 55 minutes, so I want to compare it against the current time and the following format `20151227160500`. If the current time show as `15:30PM` and I want to compare it with `20151227160500` to get the remaining time of the current program which it would show as `35 minutes`, so I create the width size for the current program.

Here is the code:

```
#get the programs list
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT channel, title, start_date, stop_date FROM programs where channel=?', [channel])
programList = list()
programs = cur.fetchall()

for ind, row in enumerate(programs):
   program_start_date = str(row[2])
   program_end_date = str(row[3])

   #convert the date formats into minutes
   minutes_start = self.parseDateTimeToMinutesSinceEpoch(program_start_date)
   minutes_end = self.parseDateTimeToMinutesSinceEpoch(program_end_date)
   minutes_length = minutes_end - minutes_start

   program_length = minutes_length

   if program_length > 165 and program_length <= 185:   #3 hours
      program_width = 2082
```

Here is the start date format:

```
20151227135000
```

Here is the stop date format:

```
20151227160500
```

Can you please show me an example of how I could use to calculating on the start and stop date format against the current time to see how many minutes the current program is remaining under the if program_length statement?

**EDIT: Here is the code:**

```
t = time.strptime("20151228000000", "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
time_now = datetime.datetime.now()
d = time_now - t
print d
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your format to datetime using datetime.strptime and then do the math, which will give you a timedelta object...

```
In [59]: import datetime
         t = datetime.datetime.strptime("20151227135000", "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
         d = datetime.datetime.now() - t
         d
Out[59]:
         datetime.timedelta(0, 5690, 225457)

In [60]: print(d.days, d.seconds, d.microseconds)
Out[60]: 0 5690 225457
```

**EDIT:** Based on the updated code try...

```
import time
t = time.mktime(time.strptime("20151228000000", "%Y%m%d%H%M%S"))
time_now = time.time()
d = time_now - t
print d
```

This will give you the seconds between the two times.

Comment: thank you very much, I don't understand what the output mean `(0, 5690, 225457)`, can you please explain what each of those number does mean?

Comment: Are you using the correct code to workout the format `20151227135000` to take away with the current time to get the output of the remaining time for the current program?

Comment: I am trying to past the variable `d = t - time_now` but it gave me the errror `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'time.struct_time'`. Do you know why? Please see in my question for the update code.

Comment: yeah but i am getting an error in this line `d = time_now - t`. Do you know why I am getting this `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'time.struct_time'`?

Comment: Can you please fix the code that I have posted? thanks!

Comment: [1] `timedelta` can be accesses via `timedelta.days`, `timedelta.seconds` and `timedelta.microseconds`. Use those for your time calculations. [2] [strftime directives](http://strftime.org/) explains all the directives. `%Y%m%d%H%M%S`, I believe is what you're looking for. [3] Does this code work? `t = datetime.datetime.strptime("20151227135000", "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")` followed by `d = datetime.datetime.now() - t`?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. The only one that I found is work which it is `t = time.strptime("20151228013500", "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")`. What do you expect me to use it with `timedelta.days, timedelta.seconds and timedelta.microseconds`?

Comment: how i can use `timedelta.days, timedelta.seconds and timedelta.microseconds` to work with the `d = time_now - t`? can you help?

Comment: Instead of `time.strptime` use `datetime.datetime.strptime`

Comment: I am getting this `TypeError: attribute of type 'NoneType' is not callable` in this line `t = datetime.datetime.strptime("20151228013500", "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")` so the only one i found which it work `t = time.strptime("20151228013500", "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")` because i am using python 2.6 version.

Comment: any idea how to get rid of the error in this line of code `d = datetime.datetime.now() - t`?

Comment: Just added update that should address... let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works great. Can you please explain what it means by the return output `-12350.7539999`?  how I can calculator to make the remaining minutes for the current program?

Comment: The output is in seconds. To get minutes divide by 60, to get to hours divide by 3600, etc. BTW, the output is negative because the comparison time was in the future, if you rerun the same example now it will be positive.